# Deploying heroku - Push failed

Tags: python, django, heroku

I need some help to solve this. I don't have much experience with Heroku, this is my first time doing it but I need to deploy some app really quickly. I've tried to disable collectstatic with

> heroku config:set DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1 -a name_of_app

But it haven't made any change.
Can anyone help me, please ? Here are logs:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.5
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.9.5
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting asgiref==3.3.1
         Downloading asgiref-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting Django==3.1.5
         Downloading Django-3.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
       Collecting django-crispy-forms==1.10.0
         Downloading django_crispy_forms-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (107 kB)
       Collecting pytz==2020.5
         Downloading pytz-2020.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
       Collecting sqlparse==0.4.1
         Downloading sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
       Installing collected packages: asgiref, sqlparse, pytz, Django, django-crispy-forms
       Successfully installed Django-3.1.5 asgiref-3.3.1 django-crispy-forms-1.10.0 pytz-2020.5 sqlparse-0.4.1
-----> $ python Project/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_784131b5/Project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "/tmp/build_784131b5/Project/manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
           settings.INSTALLED_APPS
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
           self._setup(name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
           self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
           mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_784131b5/Project/Project/settings.py", line 63, in <module>
           'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'  !     Error while running '$ python Project/manage.py collectstatic
--noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
****** Collectstatic environment variables:
       PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
       PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib/pkg-config:/app/.heroku/python/lib/pkg-config:
       DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       BPLOG_PREFIX=buildpack.python
       PWD=/tmp/build_784131b5
       HOME=/app
       LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       SOURCE_VERSION=63bcedafe22d659d05bd224cf397b61853034b97
       REQUEST_ID=0ee34e22-e730-3756-4517-01cb87e9ab5b
       ENV_DIR=/tmp/d20210517-47-48ac3y
       PYTHONPATH=.
       CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/include:/app/.heroku/python/include:
       BIN_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin
       LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:
       SHLVL=1
       LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:
       PIP_NO_PYTHON_VERSION_WARNING=1
       BUILDPACK_LOG_FILE=/dev/fd/3
       STACK=heroku-20
       BUILD_DIR=/tmp/build_784131b5
       CACHE_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache
       PATH=/app/.heroku/python/bin:/app/.heroku/vendor/bin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/vendor/
       EXPORT_PATH=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin/../export
       C_INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/include:/app/.heroku/python/include:
       DYNO=run.2787
       PROFILE_PATH=/tmp/build_784131b5/.profile.d/python.sh
       OLDPWD=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136
       _=/usr/bin/env  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.  !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your Heroku terminal run `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`, to disable collect static. by default, Heroku will run `collectstatic` on each deployment

NB: Dissabling collectstatic is a temporary solution.

for a permanent solution, you have to configure static root in settings.py, for example

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

and after that, you have to run `python manage.py collectstatic` in your local to make sure everything works locally.

then you can disable collect static with

```
heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC
```

and you can push your code to heroku with

```
git push heroku master
```